# Overflow hidden image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I cant seem to figure out how the overflow feature works.

What I try to do is: I want to make a Flexbox with one big image in the left side and two boxes in columns on the right. However I want the left image to be 100% in height and the width to be hidden so it wont stretch in height as it does now.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <style type="text/css">
    .flex-container-row {
      display: flex;
      min-height: 500px;
    }
    
    .flex-container-column {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex: 1;
      min-height: 200px;
    }
    
    .flex-item-1 {
      flex: 1;
    }
    
    .flex-item-2 {
      flex: 2;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="flex-container-row" style="background-color: #efefef; max-height: 500px;">
    <div class="flex-item-1" style="overflow: hidden;"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1588x794" style="height: 100%;" /></div>

    <div class="flex-container-column">
      <div class="flex-item-1" style="background-color: #3f3f3f;">
        <p>Hej</p>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-item-1" style="background-color: #c99494;">
        <p>Hej</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It would be very helpful if you can explain me whats wrong?

Comment: It seems to be doing what you want it to do.

Comment: Your code seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/rtm5hqxo/1?

Comment: Hi @SergChernata. Hmm but how am I able to adjust the size so I only see ex. the center middle of the image?

Comment: Hi @Pete. Hmm but how am I able to adjust the size so I only see ex. the center middle of the image?

Comment: you could use `object-fit` with a polyfill for ie